# What knowledge and skills are needed to create an App payment checkout with Stellar Network?

Tags: xlm, wallets, payments, checkout

After reading about lighting network from Bitcoin, i stumbled into this website that is "Testing" payments through lighting network which supposedly makes the transactions faster.

https://store.blockstream.com

it's working and testing site.. bugs may be present, but it's working.
Use it, pick a product and go until the checkout page so you see it.

[image: Lighting Bitcoin Payment]

it accepts payment when you send bitcoins to a QR and address allocated temporarily in the network

This made me think about payments with lumens or using stellar network for check outs in anywhere online.

Want to sell something in your website and receive lumens or fiat through stellar network? done. get this plugin working for woo comerce (wordpress extension)

But right now.. i don't see any projects doing this and the next challenge is open until 15 march. --> https://www.stellar.org/lumens/build/

the last time someone did a "wallet" that got hacked and lots of people lost their money.

How can apps be done without requiring secret key? this is a problem and also a necessity to create a portable wallet for payments (smart phone app)

i imagine myself buying stuff online, going into the checkout and scanning with my smart phone the code to make the payment and receive my item.

Also as a seller, setting a website business where i offer courses and products where users get to a checkout and get their phones to scan the code and make the payments.

*a receipt is sent through email, and a payment is received like an email.*

**What skills and knowledge is needed for this? i have the whole idea in my mind, but i have no known team to create this.**

**Is there someone out to there willing to create this ?**

I wish i could meet people to make this happen, even in my country (Ecuador) because Bitcoin is not the only crypto and i imagine the future implementing Lumens to pay for everyday stuff we need. From your own personal bank account in the stellar network.

I know it has something to do with API that is available for anyone to work with the Stellar Network, but i would like a simple guide with tutorials and people interested in creating something alike.

Sincerely,

litoid.

---

ps. There's this resource i found somewhere else.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stellar-qr

It's a standard way of generating payment links and QR codes:

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you can setup simple flow by yourself. Check the "Streaming payment events" demo (https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/examples.html#streaming-payment-events).

You just need to ask for the `memo` field, which allows you to track the inbound payments.

There is a Stellar checkout project registered for the next SBC already: https://galactictalk.org/d/804-beta-paywithstellar-instant-payment-button

I'm personally working on the advanced payment solution which includes checkout implementation right now.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://satoshipay.io/

It doesn't provide the full checkout flow, but does allow easy payments with XLM.

Comment: It has fees from a third party.... :\ I wish that could be prevented.

Comment: I've tried satoshiPay and it uses it's own wallet. I can't use my own wallet for it.....it works like paypal, (also with fees).and also you can pay for satoshi credits with paypal, visa, or from lumens wallet. you send xlm to their wallet that is attached to my web browser. I don't own the private keys for that....

Comment: I agree, both of these things are downsides. What you're asking for is on my to-do list of things I'd like to make, but that's a long list.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is some HTML, JS, CSS skills to build a nice checkout library. The Stellar SDK has a very cool feature that lets you listen to transactions (called streams) so you can match and confirm payments according to some id (order, ref, token) sent in the memo field. You also need to fetch the XLM price from any provider, generate QR Codes and validate payment confirmation to avoid hijacking the process by malicious actors.

I already built such a service in its simplest form, check it out in this test site, grab the code, improve it and create cool things:

https://myplaynet.herokuapp.com/paywithstellar

Comment: You are the same as Torkus? https://galactictalk.org/d/804-beta-paywithstellar-instant-payment-button it's the same link.. hmm Interesting, but need a better interface... just an idea, memo clickable to copy to clipboard, same for address (some people use PC). I love your project! is there anything you need help with?

Comment: That's me and all the help is highly appreciated specially testing to find out bugs and usability feedback.